# Drush 7 is not recognizing my Drupal sites, which were moved to new Virtual Host directory

Tags: drush

[image]On my laptop,  i’ve moved all my Drupal sites from a defunct AcquiaDevDesktop set up (stopped working!) into a new Virtual Host set up. I named the folder DevSites.

In trying to get the Drupal sites working properly I went to clear the cache using Drush, but Drush is not seeing these sites. When doing Drush cc all from within the root dir a Drupal site the response i get is 'No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared. ‘

Drush is still installed on my the root dir of my computer. Can someone advise on what to do so Drush sees these Drupal sites.

Should i remove first and re-install?

I'm unsure of the current version. In the command line i type 'Drush -v'
it doesn't show a version number.

[image]

Comment: use `drush --version` to see the version. Can you post a tree of your folder structure and vhost configuration?

Comment: ahh, right 7.0.0-alpha5

Comment: i added a pic to my post but it is appearing at the top of the post, hence i think it's confusing. i may take it down. there's nothing in the new dir except some websites. no hidden files or anything. drush is installed in the user root

Comment: And how does the vhost configuration for, let's say the drupal7.dev site, looks like.

Comment: Run `drush status` inside one of the folders which you think contain a Drupal site. Update your post with the output of that command and the contents of that folder. (Don't post it as an image. Copy the text from the terminal and paste it as code.)

Comment: Ok, i'm adding drush status output from within the Drupal site directory, thanks for the help! unfortunately images cannot be added to comment fields so i'll add t my post